# Does helm support Endpoints object type?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, endpoint

I've created the following to objects:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.serviceName }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}
  labels:
    chart: {{ template "chartName" . }}
    env: {{ .Values.global.env }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "10"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"

spec:
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.postgres.port}}
  selector: {}
```

for a service and its endpoint:

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.serviceName }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.namespace }}
  labels:
    chart: {{ template "chartName" . }}
    env: {{ .Values.global.env }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "10"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "before-hook-creation"
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: "{{ .Values.external.ip }}"
   ports:
     - name: "db"
       port: {{ .Values.external.port }}
```

When I use helm even in a dry run mode I can see the service object and cant see the endpoint object.

Why? Doesn't helm support all k8s objects?

Comment: How is your folder structure (Chart file, template files) and what command do you execute exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Helm is just a "templating" tool, so technically it supports everything that your underlying k8 supports.

In your case, please check that both files are in the `templates` directory

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does work. The problem was that the service and the endpoint **MUST** have same names (which I new) and **MUST** have **port names** exactly the same